# Add 'https:' before scraped href links?

Tags: python, hyperlink, scrapy, web-crawler, href

I'm trying to scrape the product detail URL and go to the corresponding page.
I have

```
product_detail_link = product.css('.title-selling-point a::attr(href)').extract()
```

This code will get the correct link:

```
'//product.suning.com/0000000000/11346320883.html'
```

However, because it doesn't have 'http:' before it, when i run

```
yield scrapy.Request(product_detail_link, callback=self.start_scraping)
```

, it cannot go to the corresponding page.
How can I add a 'https:' in front of the link I scraped?
I tried

```
yield scrapy.Request('https:'+product_detail_link, callback=self.start_scraping)
```

and

```
product_detail_link = 'https:'+product.css('.title-selling-point a::attr(href)').extract()
```

But both do not work, I guess it's because the href is not a string so I cannot just add something in front of it? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: what error does it says when you try to add html in front of it - like you showed?

Comment: Have you tried `https:`?

Comment: @S.Strempfer sorry, that was a typo I made for posting the question, I just fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `extract` method which returns list of links instead of one link. So you need to loop through all links and add `http` or `https` to all links.

if you need one link, you should use `get()` or `extract_first()` method